# why not load returned data from ajax request in jstree

Tags: jstree

I make an ajax request in jstree, I see returned data in success methodand return this data.. but tree still empty.
img:[image]

Jstree:

```
$('#tree_2').jstree({
            'plugins': ["checkbox" ,"ui"],
            'core' : {
                'data' : {
                    "url" : "../../Controller/ActiveDirectoryController.php5?"+datas,
                    "data" : function (node) {
                        debugger
                        return { "id" : node.id };
                    },
                    "success": function(result_){
                        result = JSON.parse(result_);
                        debugger
                        return [result.Objects];
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

php:

```
 if(in_array("user",$aDobjects[$i]["objectclass"]))
                    {
                        $result[] = array("id"=>$i+1,"text"=>$aDobjects[$i]["name"][0],"children"=>false,"parent"=>"-2", "distinguishedName"=>$aDobjects[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $result[] = array("id"=>$i+1,"text"=>$aDobjects[$i]["name"][0],"children"=>true,"parent"=>"-2", "distinguishedName"=>$aDobjects[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jstree events, bind post functions inside it also check the data(stop same node post) and refresh tree with respond, here how I solved my problem:

```
var slctedText ="";
$('#tree_2').jstree({
    'plugins': ["types","json_data" ,"ui"],
    'core': {
        "themes" : {
            "responsive": false,
            "icons":false
        },
        'data': [{}]
    },
    "types" : {
        "default" : {
            "icon" : "fa fa-folder icon-state-warning icon-lg"
        },
        "file" : {
            "icon" : "fa fa-file icon-state-warning icon-lg"
        }
    }
}).bind('before_open.jstree', function (e, data) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    setUpButtons();
    if( data.node.text.indexOf("DC=")>-1)//!passOpen ||
        return;
    if(data.node.text == slctedText)
        return;
    debugger
    keyValuePair = []
    slctedText = data.node.text;
    var objParam = data.node.original.subtext;//prepareParam(slctedText, data.node.parents);
    var params = {
        action: "getSubAdObjects",
        objectParam: objParam,
        serverIP: serverip,
        port: port,
        domain: domain,
        username: username,
        password: password
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../Controller/ActiveDirectoryController.php5",
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: params,
        success: function (result) {
            passOpen = false;
            if(result.Objects.length>0)
            {
                treeData_ = prepareObjectsforTree(result.Objects);
                resfreshJSTree(treeData_);
                debugger
            }
            $("#mdlObjects").modal("show");
            $("#divfailed").hide();
            event.theme ='lime';
            event.heading ='<i class=\'fa fa-check\'></i> Process Completed';
            event.message ='Active Directory objects retrieved successfully.';
            ntf(event);

        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {

        }
    })
})
```

And this server function return response data from server:

```
public function parseADobjectsForTree($aDobjects){
        try
        {
            $result = array();
            $singleObject = array();
            unset($aDobjects["count"]);
            for($i=0; $i < count($aDobjects); $i++)
            {
                if(array_key_exists("name", $aDobjects[$i]))
                {
                    if(in_array("user",$aDobjects[$i]["objectclass"]))
                    {
                        $result[] = array("id"=>$i+1, "text"=>$aDobjects[$i]["name"][0],"subtext"=>$aDobjects[$i]["distinguishedname"][0] );//"li_attr"=>"jstree-leaf"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $result[] = array("id"=>$i+1, "text"=>$aDobjects[$i]["name"][0], "subtext"=>$aDobjects[$i]["distinguishedname"][0],"children"=> array());//"li_attr"=>"jstree-closed",
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are executing inside `success` does not influence the data that jstree receives. So basically jstree gets the data that your server returns, not the object that you modify in the `success` callback.

Make sure your server response is in the required jsTree format. If you can not match the format look into the jQuery ajax `dataFilter` option.

It is also a good idea to provide proper headers:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

That way the client side will know that your response is actually JSON.